# $(document).load does not fire alert MVC/Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'll admit I'm new at MVC razor/jquery.

---

in my _Layout.cshtml
this works:

---

```
<body onload="alert('in the body');">
```

---

this is code in _Layout.cshtml:
The$(document).load does not fire
(neither does $(window).load)

---

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles/Courses.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).load(function() {
    alert('test');

</script>

</head>
<body>
```

---

This is rendered when page runs, used "View Source" to get html below

---

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/Courses.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function() {
alert('test');
</script>

</head>
<body>
```

---

I moved the jquery and javascript over to the Index.chstml file and it still wouldn't fire.
I referenced the .js file first by dragging it over in VS 2010.
This didn't work.
Then I tried this syntax in _Layout.chshtml; didn't work:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
```

---

any insights/help/. . . .solutions are welcome thank you

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Note you were also missing the closing `})` on the function.

Comment: yes, and my needs are met thank you very much. However, My question above was for $(document).load and once I added the missing closing stuff it still wouldn't work. However $(document).ready is just what I need. $(window).load works too, just not $(document).load